Trying to get MenuItem from '@szhsin/react-menu' to overlap other PlayerCardMini objects
I'm using React js and @szhsin/react-menu to create a way for the user to create their own formation and edit the formation. If the user right clicks on an object, a menu pops up where they can select from several options. My current issue is that no matter what I try to do, the MenuItem and MenuButton objects will always be overlapped by other PlayerCardMini objects generated by my 'Formations' component. I have tried changing the z-index for everything to no avail. Here is an example of the problem:
[Example of problem] (https://i.sstatic.net/jyeCwpxF.png)
Here is my code for the Menu and PlayerCard object.
//PlayerCardMini.js
const PlayerCardMenu = () => {
        return (
            <Menu 
                menuButton={<MenuButton
                    className="menu-button"
                    style={{ marginLeft: '-50px', 
                        left: `${menuState.x}px`, 
                        top: `${menuState.y}px`, display: 'flex', float: 'left'}}     
                >Edit</MenuButton>}
                onClose={handleCloseMenu}>
                <MenuItem style={{position: 'relative', zIndex: 100}}
                    onClick={() => {
                        if (isQueue) {
                            console.log('Player being removed from queue at index: ', index);
                            removePlayer(setFunction, index);
                        } else {
                            removePlayer(position);
                        }
                        handleCloseMenu(); // Optionally, you might want to close the menu here as well
                    }}
                >
                    Remove Player
                </MenuItem>
                {!isQueue && <MenuItem onClick={() => { handleSwitch() }} disabled={!canSwitch}>Switch Player</MenuItem>}

                <MenuItem onClick={toggleStatsPopup}>Show Stats Menu</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseMenu}>Exit</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div onDoubleClick={() => handleDoubleClick(player)}
            className="player-card-mini"
            onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}
            ref={combineRefs}
            style={{
                opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
                cursor: 'grab',
            }}>
            <div className="left-panel">
                <div className="player-info">
                    <h2 style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}>{player.overall}</h2>
                    <h3 style={{ fontSize: getPosition().length > 2 ? '12px' : '16px' }}>
                        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: getPosition() }} />
                    </h3>
                    <img src={player.clubLogo} alt="Club Logo" className="club-logo" />
                    <img src={player.flag} alt="Country Flag" className="country-flag" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="right-panel">
                <img src={imageUrl} onError={handleImageError} alt={player.name} className="player-photo" />
                <p style={{ marginBottom: '10px', fontSize: '14px' }}>{getLastName(player.name)}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="player-card-menu-portal"></div>
            {menuState.isOpen && <PlayerCardMenu />}
            {statsPopupOpen && <PlayerStatsPopup
                player={player}
                saveAllChanges={saveAllChanges}
                onClose={toggleStatsPopup}
                getPlayerStats={getPlayerStats} />}
        </div>
    );

PlayerCardMini.css
.player-card-mini {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 150px;
    /* Adjust width as needed */
    height: 200px;
    /* Adjust height as needed */
    background-image: url('empty_card.png');
    /* Set the background image */
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 2; 
    margin-left: -7px;
}

.player-card-mini .left-panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

.player-card-mini .right-panel {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.player-card-mini .player-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.player-card-mini .player-photo {
    width: 75px;
    /* Adjust width as needed */
    height: 75px;
    /* Adjust height as needed */
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.player-card-mini .club-logo {
    width: 25px;
    /* Adjust width as needed */
    height: 25px;
    /* Adjust height as needed */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.player-card-mini .country-flag {
    width: 15px;
    /* Adjust width as needed */
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.player-card-mini .szh-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.menu-button {
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #007BFF;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3 ease;
    z-index: 5;
}

.menu-button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;   /* Darker shade on hover */
}

How my Positions are generated within Formation.js (Each includes a PlayerCard object):
const generatePositions = (positionType, numPlayers) => {
    return Array.from({ length: numPlayers }, (_, index) => {
      const { originalName, modifiedName } = generatePositionName(positionType, index, numPlayers);
      const positionKey = `${positionType}-${index}`
      return <Position
        key={positionKey}
        position={originalName}
        modifiedPosition={modifiedName}
        player={positions[positionKey]}
        highlightedPosition={highlightedPosition}
        setHighlightedPosition={setHighlightedPosition}
        removePlayer={() => removePlayer(positionKey)}
        saveAllChanges={saveAllChanges}
        switchPlayer={switchPlayer}
        getPlayerStats={getPlayerStats}
      />;
    });
  };

const positionGroups = [
    { type: 'Striker', positions: generatePositions('Striker', formation.strikers) },
    { type: 'aMidfielder', positions: generatePositions('aMidfielder', formation.aMidfielders) },
    { type: 'Midfielder', positions: generatePositions('Midfielder', formation.midfielders) },
    { type: 'dMidfielder', positions: generatePositions('dMidfielder', formation.dMidfielders) },
    { type: 'Defender', positions: generatePositions('Defender', formation.defenders) },
    { type: 'Goalkeeper', positions: generatePositions('Goalkeeper', 1) } // Assuming generatePositions can handle the goalkeeper as a special case
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const allPositionNames = positionGroups.flatMap(group =>
      group.positions.map(child => child.props.modifiedPosition)
    );
    setPositionNames(allPositionNames);
    // Only call these functions if players are already initialized
    findBestPlayers(allPositionNames, queue);
  }, [formation]);

  return (
    <div className="soccer-field">
      <div className="positions-container">
        {positionGroups.map(group => (
          <div className="positions-section" key={group.type}>
            {group.positions}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

Position component:
return (
<div ref={drop} className="position" onDoubleClick={() => handleDoubleClick()}>
<div className={empty-card ${isHighlighted ? 'highlight' : ''}}>
{positionName}
{player && (

)}


);
//Formations.css
.soccer-field {
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-image: url('./resources/soccerfield.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center bottom;
    height: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: -1;
}

.positions-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 1;
}

.positions-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.position {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.empty-card.highlight { 
    border-color: rgb(25, 0, 255);
}

.empty-card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 150px;
    /* Adjust width as needed */
    height: 200px;
    /* Adjust height as needed */
    background-image: url('empty_card.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    z-index: 0;
    transform: scale(0.9);
}

.empty-card .position-label {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

